# iPhone Table View Section Headers

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header, rows

I have a TableView with custom cells.

I need to be able to put 2 section headers called Instruction and Reference.

I need 7 rows for the Instruction section and 3 rows for the Reference section.

Here is how I have coded my table view. I know it is not ideal but I am new to this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [listOfItems count];}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Anatomy";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anatomy.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];

        break;
    case 1:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Indications";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Info.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];

        break;
    case 2:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Medications";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pill.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];

        break;
    case 3:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Equipment";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spanner.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
        break;
    case 4:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Procedure";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"procedure.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
        break;
    case 5:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Complications";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"complication.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
        break;
    case 6:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Procedure Video";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"procedure.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
        break;
    case 7:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Calculations";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"math.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
        break;
    case 8:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Videos & Images";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
        break;
    case 9:
        cell.customLabel.text = @"Feedback";
        cell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"feedback.png"];
        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return cell;}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    AnatomyWeb1 *test1 = [[AnatomyWeb1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnatomyWeb1" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test1 animated:YES];

    [test1 release];
}
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    Indications *test1 = [[Indications alloc] initWithNibName:@"Indications" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test1 animated:YES];

    [test1 release];
}
if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    Medication *test6 = [[Medication alloc] initWithNibName:@"Medication" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test6 animated:YES];

    [test6 release];
}
if (indexPath.row == 3) {

    ProcedureWeb1 *test3 = [[ProcedureWeb1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProcedureWeb1" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test3 animated:YES];

    [test3 release];
}
if (indexPath.row == 4) {
    ProcedureWeb3 *test3 = [[ProcedureWeb3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProcedureWeb3" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test3 animated:YES];

    [test3 release];
}
if (indexPath.row == 5) {
    Complications2 *test4 = [[Complications2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Complications2" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test4 animated:YES];

    [test4 release];
}
if (indexPath.row == 6) {
    [self video1];
}
if (indexPath.row == 7) {
    Calculations1 *test3 = [[Calculations1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Calculations1" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test3 animated:YES];

    [test3 release];

}
if (indexPath.row == 8) {
    VideosAndImages *test3 = [[VideosAndImages alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideosAndImages" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test3 animated:YES];

    [test3 release];

}
if (indexPath.row == 9) {
    Feedback *test11 = [[Feedback alloc] initWithNibName:@"Feedback" bundle:nil];

    test11.previousViewController=self;

    test11.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [self presentModalViewController:test11 animated:YES];

    [test11 release];
}}
```

Thanks for any suggestions guys.

Comment: You need to paste the code (rather than a screengrab) into the question, select it and then mark it as code (the "binary" icon in the editor). :-)

Comment: Why did you post screenshots instead of code?

Comment: Will post the code when I get home, just walking to my car. sorry I thought there might have been too much code to post.

Comment: Hi All. Code Uploaded. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as you have used indexPath.row you would use indexPath.section for identifying the currently active section. For example in cellForRowAtIndexPath you could have two nested switch statements, one for the section, one for the row.

Populate the other method for the tableView (without claiming completeness here):

`numberOfSectionsInTableView` will return 2 (two sections),
`numberOfRowsInSection` will return 7 or 3 depending of the section active,
`titleForHeaderInSection` will return (if needed) the string you want to see on top of your section.

And on a personal note: you might not want to call your view **test1**, better declare it as

```
AnatomyWeb * anatomyWeb = ...
Indications * indications = ...
```

You are using test3 multiple time and a "testX" naming style can be pain to debug

Comment: Hi Olaf, Thanks for the reply. Not sure how to incorporate this as I have no idea about currently active sections etc. Can you elaborate further on this? Thanks also for the advice about my naming conventions. I really must change them! :)

Comment: for example the tableview will automatically call `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.   Add a switch or if case to detect which section is active. Similar in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath `. indexPath has two fields: row and section.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help Olaf. Did exactly what you said and my problem is solved. Now for those naming conventions!